# How to run a webapp in browser using localhost?

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-applications, server, localhost

I have a program in node.js. I ran the code using "node main.js". It starts listening. When I try to open the link, "https://localhost:8080" it displays, "It works !

If you're seeing this page via a web browser,"
which is usually popped up after tomcat installation. how can i fix it and run my code?

Comment: Show your `main.js`.

Comment: Hey Madhu, can you show the code of your main.js? Would be better to understand what is your problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You probably have a tomcat server running on the same port. Shut it down and run the node.js server only